# Python: Europe date of dataframe to Europe unix timestamp

Tags: python, dataframe, date, unix, timestamp

I tried to convert my Europe "Date" column into a Europe unix timestamp column. Unfortunately, I always get the wrong unix timestamp... My dataframe looks like this:

```
      Index            Date Second     Measurement
0     0 2020-02-24 10:52:38  0.000  0.001155460021
1     1 2020-02-24 10:52:39  0.109  0.001124729984
2     2 2020-02-24 10:52:40  0.203  0.001119069988
```

I tried the following code, but I always get for the first value (10:52:38) 1582541558. But it should be **1582537958** Does the problem depends on, that python "does not know" that I am using Europe CET?

```
df["DateUnix"] = df.Date.map(lambda x: x.timestamp())  #fail

timestamp = (df.Date - pd.Timestamp("1970-01-01")) // pd.Timedelta('1s')    #fail
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`localize` the datetime objects with your desired timezone before you extract the timestamp, e.g.

```
import pandas as pd

dt = pd.to_datetime('2020-02-24 10:52:38').tz_localize(tz='Europe/Berlin')
ts = dt.timestamp()

assert int(ts) == 1582537958
```

Why? A datetime object you get from a string like `'2020-02-24 10:52:38'` will be naive, meaning it does not know about a timezone. If you then call `.timestamp()`, Python will assume that the datetime object belongs in the timezone of your operating system and convert to UTC before returning the POSIX timestamp.

Example:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
ts_naive = datetime(2020, 5, 15).timestamp()
ts_utc = datetime(2020, 5, 15, tzinfo=timezone.utc).timestamp()
# my OS is on UTC+2, so ts_naive should be ts_utc - 2*3600:
assert ts_utc - 2*3600 == ts_naive
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.
If I adapt your code to mine:

df['Date'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.to_datetime(df.Date)).tz_localize(tz='Europe/Berlin')

I get: >>2020-02-24 10:52:38+01:00<<
which is not correct, because of the +01

Comment: 2020-02-24 10:52:38+01:00 is correct since in February, DST was inactive, so Europe/Berlin was at UTC+1